# Junction table in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a Database with the tables:

```
Doctor (doctorID, specialty, doctorname)

Suffers(patientID, diseaseName)

Treats (junction table) (doctorID, patientID)
```

I need to write a query which outputs patientID and DiseaseName of patients who have a disease which is not yet treated by a doctor having the disease as their specialty.

How do I do that?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and desired output?

Comment: Your schema looks flawed - if a patient has multiple diseases the junction table does not know which disease is being treated - and suffers may have 1-n diseases per patient. Or are you just assuming for this homework question that a patient can only have 1 disease?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is 'query which outputs patientID and DiseaseName'  then doctor seems irrelevant since non existence in junction table is enough to decide patient is not under treatment.

```
select * 
from suffers
where not exists (select 1 from treats where suffers.patient_id = treats.patient_id);
```